# Extrema min-max over constrained $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z)=xe^{yz}$

$D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 25,3x^2+y^2+z^2=27\}$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
f_x=e^{yz}=0\\
f_y=xze^{yz}=0\\
f_x=xye^{yz}=0
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

from here I can't see any critical point.

Now in order to find the critical point constrained on $D$, I'll use the Lagrange multiplier method:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
e^{yz}=zx\lambda+6x\mu\\
xze^{yz}=2y\lambda+2y\mu\\
xye^{yz}=2z\lambda+2z\mu\\
x^2+y^2+z^2-25=0\\
3x^2+y^2+z^2-27=0
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

From that system I found :

$(\pm1,\sqrt{12},\sqrt{12}),(\pm1,-\sqrt{12},-\sqrt{12}),(\pm1,\sqrt{12},-\sqrt{12}),(\pm1,-\sqrt{12},\sqrt{12})$

pugging them back into the function :

$f(1,\pm\sqrt{12},\pm\sqrt{12})=e^{12}$

$f(-1,\pm\sqrt{12},\mp\sqrt{12})=-e^{12}$

$f(1,\pm\sqrt{12},\pm\sqrt{12})=e^{-12}=\frac{1}{e^{12}}$

**Questions**:

**1)**

Can I state that $f(1,\pm\sqrt{12},\pm\sqrt{12})=e^{12}$,$f(1,\pm\sqrt{12},\pm\sqrt{12})=e^{-12}=\frac{1}{e^{12}}$ are a maximum , $f(-1,\pm\sqrt{12},\mp\sqrt{12})=-e^{12}$ a minimum , without using The $3x3$ hessiam matrix ?

**2)**

Judging by the fact that I didn't find any  critical points by setting $f_x=0,f_y=0,f_z=0$ does that mean there are not critical points (max-min) inside $D$ or outside it, so the only critical points are only those constrained that I found before ?

Comment: Did you find any critical points with just the sharp constraint (the second one) that still are in $D$? So with just one lagrange multiplier?

Answer (score 1):

The set $D$ is a rotational elliptical surface, bounded by two circles. There are no $3$-variables critical points to consider.

Write
$$y=r\cos\phi,\quad z=r\sin\phi\ .$$
Then we have to extremise the function
$$g(x,r,\phi):=xe^{r^2\sin(2\phi)/2}$$
under the constraints
$$x^2+r^2\leq25,\quad 3x^2+r^2=27\ .\tag{1}$$
Given $x>0$ and $r\geq0$ the function $\phi\mapsto g(x,r,\phi)$ is maximal  when $\sin(2\phi)=1$. We therefore have to maximize
$$g_\max(x,r):=xe^{r^2/2}$$
under the constraints $(1)$ and $x>0$, $r\geq0$. It is then clear that the minimum of $f$ is obtained as $g_\min=-g_\max$ by replacing $x_\max$ by $x_\min=-x_\max$, keeping the same $r$.